# Computed column in SQL View

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, calculated-columns

My current view produces this kind of output...

```
Product1 Product2
Jet      Ski
Water    Polo
```

Could i use a computed column in a view, in order getting results like these?

```
Product1 Product2 Computed
Jet      Ski      Jet Ski
Water    Polo     Water Polo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
select Product1, Product2, Product1 + ' ' + Product2 as [computed]
  from my_table
```

Comment: Obviously, you need more coffee

Answer (score 3):

Computed columns are defined at the table level, but why not simply concatenate?

```
SELECT 
    Product1, 
    Product2, 
    Product1 + ' ' + Product2 AS FullProductName 
FROM 
    MyProductTable
```

Comment: I think that's what he's asking, if he can do that.